# Cash Register Returns Amount Remaining Plus Change on Secondary Payment

Tags: java, if-statement

I thought I had this correct, but when I tried splitting the payments in my "Cash Register", it returned the correct change on both the second and first payments, but on the second payment it includes the third if statement I placed, and it gives the change as well.

For example:

```
Price: $100.00
Sales tax = $6.00
Total amount due = $106.00
Payment = $50.00
Amount Remaining: $56.00
Payment $50.00
Amount Remaining: $6.00
Your Change Is: $44.00
```

Here is the offending code segment in question. Any help is appreciated.

```
 public void makePayment (double payment){


    if (payment < 0){
        System.out.println("Insufficient Funds. Please Use Another Method Of Payment");
    }

    if (payment < currentAmountDue ){
        currentAmountDue = currentAmountDue - payment;
        System.out.println("Amount Remaining: " + fmt.format(currentAmountDue));
        dailySales = currentAmountDue + dailySales;
    }

    if (payment > currentAmountDue){
        dailySales = dailySales + currentAmountDue;
        currentAmountDue = payment - currentAmountDue;
        System.out.println("Your Change Is: " + fmt.format(currentAmountDue));
        numberOfCustomers = numberOfCustomers + 1;
        dailySales = currentAmountDue + dailySales;
    }

    if (payment == currentAmountDue){
        dailySales = dailySales + currentAmountDue;
        numberOfCustomers = numberOfCustomers + 1;
        currentAmountDue = 0;
        System.out.println("Thank you for your money!");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should never use `==` to compare doubles. Because you can not precisely represent all numbers with a floating point number, this is very likely to fail when you mathematically expect numbers to be equal.

Comment: Usually it is already a bad idea to use floating-point-variables of any kind to store amounts of money...

Comment: It would be better to use an `int` or a `long` to store money and use the last two digits for your `decimal` number, this will ensure accuracy a lot better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy to spot if you walk through your code for the second payment.

Upon entry `currentAmountDue=56` and `payment=50`, so

```
if (payment < currentAmountDue )
```

is true and you do

```
 currentAmountDue = currentAmountDue - payment;
```

So now `currentAmountDue=6` and still `payment=50` and you execute the next `if`-statment:

```
if (payment > currentAmountDue){
```

Which also evaluates as `true`.

You would only want to execute one of your `if`-branches, so you best change all of your `if` except the first to `else if`.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I'm a communications major trying to broaden their horizons, so thanks for helping! That makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: "So now currentAmountDue=56" I think you meant it would be currentAmountDue= **6** after completion of the if-statement? (Thereby satisfying next if-statement)